# error for android.R.layout.custom

Tags: android, android-listview

I create a XML layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="4dip"
        android:paddingRight="4dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to fill this layout by below code :

```
package ir.smspeik.sms;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyListView extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView selection;
    String[] names;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listlayout);
        names = new String[] { "sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday",
                "thrusday", "friday", "saturday", };
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.custom,
                R.id.label, names));
        selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        selection.setText(names[position]);
    }
}
```

I have two warnings and an error.
warnings are in xml file : 
1. This tag and its children can be replaced by one  and a compound drawable
2. [Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image

error in MyListView
1. the eclipse doesn't know android.R.layout.custom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `R.layout.custom` instead of `android.R.layout.custom`

Comment: see this tuts http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html